# How to select an element according a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

HowI can select an element according a value? for example I want to select an input in `RadiobuttonList` control that has `value=2`.

thanks

Comment: You should at least show us the **rendered** html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#{id of RadiobuttonList} input[value="2"]').attr('checked', 'checked')
```

or for jQuery 1.6+:

```
$('#{id of RadiobuttonList} input[value="2"]').prop('checked', true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$("#<%=rbl.ClientID%> input[value=2]").attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('#<%=rbl.ClientID %>').find("input[value=2]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

**Note**  rbl is id of the radiobuttonlist

Comment: you shouldn't use `find` if it's a new jQuery object. you use find for existed jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this css selector:

```
input[type="radio"][value="2"]
```

in jquery

```
$('input[type="radio"][value="2"]')
```